# How does one differentiate a "conceptual metaphor" from other kinds of metaphor?

Tags: semantics, metaphors, linguistics

There is a rather long list of metaphors: standard (stock) metaphors, extended metaphors,
visual metaphors, implied metaphors, mixed metaphors, allegorical metaphors, absolute metaphors
dead metaphors, etc.
In terms of all having one property in common, I have (thus far) read that they all involve a transfer of quality (from one item/idea to another) in some way.  I have not found a lengthy, detailed discussion on this topic.

Can these other types of metaphor be (in some way) subsumed under the "conceptual metaphor"? And what are the characteristics that differentiate a conceptual metaphor from these other kinds of metaphor?

Comment: Can you explain where you've been reading this, and what definition of conceptual metaphor you are using? There are many different theories about metaphors, each with different terminology. (I thought there were similar questions on here but there are so many about metaphors I've not found one.) Also, a lot of the types of metaphor you give (extended, mixed, dead, etc) are not mutually exclusive - they are terms that describe metaphors not separate categories of metaphors.

Comment: I have predominately read Ullmann's work "Semantics. An Introduction to the Science of Meaning", and "Knowledge, Representation and Metaphor" by Cornwell, et al.

Comment: With a "conceptual metaphor" essentially, as far as I know, we can look at the metaphor in terms of a "source" and "target domain", but as far as I can tell all these other metaphor types can be essentially viewed in this way, too.

Comment: They're extended metaphors. [Nordquist](https://www.thoughtco.com/what-is-conceptual-metaphor-1689899) has a reasonable article showing one analysis. He includes different phrasings of the 'time = money' metaphor from Lakoff etc.

Comment: Here's [another one about Time Is Money](http://websites.umich.edu/~jlawler/TIM.pdf), in some detail. "Conceptual" metaphors means [what Lakoff & Johnson talk about](http://websites.umich.edu/~jlawler/L&J-Lg-Review.pdf); there's a lot of sloppy terminology around metaphor, since you have to use it to talk about it.